# How do I compare Firebase Database snapshots with a text?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am coding an application in Swift with Firebase. How do I compare a Firebase Database Snapshot with something else? For the people they do not understand me, here's an example:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("Person").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (PersonSnap) in
let PersonID = PersonSnap.value

if PersonID == "HelloWorld" {
//Code
}
  }
```

How do I make this `if PersonID == "HelloWorld"` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine - the only issue is that *PersonSnap.value* could be a number of things so we need to tell the compiler what it is. This question assumes the following Firebase structure

```
your_firebase
   users
      uid_x
         Person: "HelloWorld"
```

the code within the Firebase closure to read that would be

```
let PersonID = snapshot.value as! String
if PersonID == "HelloWorld" {
    print(PersonID)
} else {
    print("the string was not HelloWorld")
}
```

Note that we are unwrapping the optional *PersonSnap.value* and defining it as a String.

Also note that force unwrapping options may get you into trouble if it's nil. Only force unwrap if you know for certain the variable will be populated. An safer alternative is *guard*

```
guard let myId = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
print(myId)
```

and if you want to be super safe and very stylish, use *if let*

```
if let thisId = snapshot.value as? String {
    if thisId == "HelloWorld" {
        print(thisId)
    } else {
        print("the string was not HelloWorld")
    }
}
```